# Type hint for any object in function calls

Tags: php

How do I explicitly type-check in PHP that I received an object as a function argument?

This would satisfy my requirements only if it was a working example:

```
function example(object $argument)
{
    $argument->property = 'something';
}
```

(The latter gives me "Argument must be an instance of object, instance of ... given")

`is_object()` does not constitute type checking because I want a program fail and fail hard in case if it wasn't provided an object.

On can argue that I can do `assert(is_object($argument))` but assertions could be turned off thus avoiding this type of type checking. Throwing in any conditional expression throwing exceptions doesn't make it any better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TL;DR - According to [the manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.typehinting.php), such a hint is not (yet?) possible.

You could use an `stdClass` hint to test for a generic object:

```
function example(\stdClass $argument)
{
    echo $argument->foo;
}
```

Or make all your classes derive from your own base class or implement some interface:

```
function example(MyBaseClass $argument)
{
}
```

Or, simply check the variable type manually using `is_object()`:

```
function example($argument)
{
    if (!is_object($argument)) {
        trigger_error("Invalid argument", E_USER_ERROR);
        // or: throw new InvalidArgumentException();
    }
    // it's an object
}
```

That said, checking for any object doesn't provide much information to the application on the whole; an explicit class to test against would be the way to go.

Comment: "Argument 1 passed to ... must be an instance of stdClass, instance of ... given"

Comment: @sanmai if you know exactly what class you want to pass, put it in instead of `stdClass`

Comment: @sanmai If you're in another namespace you need `\stdClass`.

Comment: @Jack it could be any class, else there be no question

Comment: You can't typehint any class directly in the params, then you must use Ben's solution.

Comment: calling `is_object()` is not what I want; I updated my question to reflect that

Comment: @sanmai You want to check whether an argument is any object, but `is_object()` is not what you want? That's confusing.

Comment: @Jack yup, see updated question; BTW I'm fine if that's entirely not possible in PHP. Just want to know for sure.

Comment: @sanmai Updated answer; basically, there's no hint for "any object".

Answer (score 1):

Checking the function parameter is called type hinting:

```
class ConcreteClass {...}
function(ConcreteClass obj) {...}
```

This is for checking generally:

```
if ($obj instanceof ConcreteClass) {
    //do stuff
}
```

or

```
if (is_object($obj)) {
    //do stuff
}
```

I'd prefer type hinting and instanceof.

Comment: `is_object()` does not constitute type checking

Comment: True. But it will tell you if it is any object or not. I don't like it either, but it's still a possibility to make sure it is a object.